# How to pass string without single/double quotes to another function in a loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, decision-tree

I have extracted 1000 rules from decision tree and saved in a dataframe. Below are the sample rule

```
(age > 25) & (Tenure < 48)
```

Now I want to check how many observations in a pandas dataframe (Data_rules) are following each rule. Basically I want to check length of dataframe after applying above rule. Below are the code I have written

```
for i in Data_rules.index: 
    temp = len(train[Data_rules['Rules'][i]]) 
    output.append(temp)
```

This code is throwing me a 'key error' because Data_rules['Rules'][i] will give each rule in a form of string and starts with single quotes like '(age > 25) & (Tenure < 48)' but we need to pass this rule without quotes to train dataset. Can anyone help me on this please.

Comment: Please provide full trace back of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) is for, here's an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"age": [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35], "Tenure": [1, 1, 1, 1, 50, 47]})
result = df.query("(age > 25) & (Tenure < 48)")

print(result)
```

Output:

```
   age  Tenure
5   35      47
```